# Print even numbers using Iterators

Tags: java, iterator

How to print even numbers from an array using Iterators (This is an exercise that professor sent me and by Iterator he means using `hasNext()`, `getNext()`)

I don't know how to use those in a code

```
public void printEven(){
    for(int i=0; i<nrs.length;i++){
        if(nrs[i]%2==0){
            System.out.println(nrs[i]);
        }
}
```

Comment: try this: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_using_iterator.htm

Answer (score 1):

Start reading [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/collection.html). Then please read some [tutorials](http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=235) and get knowledge about [Iterator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html). Then try your hands on conding. A sample implementation for your problem is as below:

```
//Considering 0 as even number. 

public void printEven(int[] array){
    List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(array);
    Iterator<Integer> itr = list.iterator();
    while(itr.hasNext()) {
       int number = itr.next();
       if(number%2==0) {
          System.out.println(number);
       }
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

According to wikipedia [[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/0_%28number%29#In_mathematics)], 0 is an even number. So:

> 0 is the integer immediately preceding 1. Zero is an even number, because it is divisible by 2.

```
public void printEvenNumbers(int[] numbers) {
   List<Integer> numsList = Arrays.asList(numbers)
   for (Iterator<Integer> it = numsList.iterator(); it.hasNext(); ) { 
       int num = it.next();
       if (num % 2 == 0) {
           System.out.println(num);
       }
   }
}
```